# Pasting a rendered link to a rich-text column with the list in datasheet view

Tags: 2010, 2013, html, rich-text, datasheet

I'm trying to paste a rendered link, i.e., a link from within a Word or Excel file, into a rich-text column in SharePoint's datasheet view... Pasting from Excel, I get a working link, but it's the URL and not the link text; pasting from Word, I get the link text, but it's not a link - just plain text... Ditto when the source is rendered HTML.

[image: demonstration image]

I've tried changing the format of the source, e.g., HTML, RichText, but it doesn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying and pasting, you should try going into **Insert -> Link -> From Address** as shown in below screenshot:

[image: Insert Link]

This will bring dialog as shown below:

[image: Insert Link Dialog]

This will give you option to write both Text and Link.

Also instead of just copying from Excel/Word, you can right-click on the hyperlink and click **Edit Hyperlink** option.. This will allow you to copy both Text and link separately!

Comment: This solution doesn't work for my case, as I am using Foundation 2010 (another user edited the post to remove the tag; I should have retained, perhaps...) That said, your answer is otherwise applicable. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, in my case):[image]

I had the best results copying the links from a rendered HTML file. Copying the links from Microsoft Word and Excel documents was also successful. Unfortunately, you will also be pasting formatting with your code.

I opted to access the Ribbon > Markup > HTML > Edit HTML Source while using inline editing on the list. Less than ideal, so very welcome to more ideas.